# Does the Malaga airport bus have luggage racks?

Tags: buses, malaga

Bus line A connects Malaga airport to the city center. Does it have racks for larger (checked-bag size) luggage?

Comment: [This page](https://www.emtmalaga.es/consultas) of the Malaga Bus System is a portal for asking questions. The site is in Spanish, but [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) is a thing. Have you asked them?

Comment: To be clearer: we expect users to try and find the answer on their own, and let us know what (if anything) is discovered. Take a look at [this Help page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The airport shuttle (airport to central bus station) has low level racks where you can put big luggage.
Sometimes if bus is full you’ll just have to stand with it. Your smaller luggage you’ll keep with you (no overhead racks).

To get to the bus, go straight out of the airport doors, through the crowd!, to the road. The bus stop serves several lines. There is an electronic departure board. Being spain, there is only a loose queue, or crowd, but you’ll get on.

The driver issues tickets. Last time I went it was 5€  Don’t offer a large note, you’ll end up clutching your change, your bags, and being shoved by the old lady behind who wants a seat!

You’ll know when you get to the bus station. Barrier for the bus, it parks. Ticket hall and exit straight ahead.

Ask more if needed. Have fun.